# Weird windows 7 networking problem

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a strange problem with windows 7. My network connection used to work fine, then one day, all of the sudden it stopped wotking. I tryed everything possible to get it working (ipgonfig /renew, etc.), and after a while found that what helped, was to simply first disable, and then enable my network adapter from device manager.

Now the problem is that every time i restart my computer it stops working again and i have to do the same routine every time, which is starting to get bit anoying. I also tryed installing newest network drivers, but that didn't change anything. The adapter is NVIDIA nForce 10/100 Mbps Ethernet.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/77804/weird-networking-problem-linksys-windows-7

Answer (score 2):

my experience with this prblem is windows update. IF i for some reason update the drivers for my realtek card it will not work. and the only way for ME to fix the problem was to roll a earlyer version of my win7.

Comment: I have had this same issue recently with windows update - a realtek driver was applied in windows update that caused erratic behavior. You can check the update history to see if that was the case then roll back the driver.

Comment: ahh... that i actually did not know. thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Re-enabling the network adapter causes it to renew its connection to the router.

If you do have a router, I would have a look at its lease-time setting. It might be set to give your computer a very short lease on the connection. The default lease-time is normally at least 24 hours.

If you need more help, please supply more info about your network architecture and internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

are you using windows update? Sometimes windows update renews your Network-adapter driver. Try to set back the old driver in the devices manager.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling back the driver for the NIC should solve your problem.

Comment: What leads you to believe it is the drivers? Can you provide documentation about his drivers that suggest a problem with the version he is on?

Comment: @MaQleod: You never know if you don't try...

Comment: @Tom: I agree, and there is no harm in suggesting it as a comment, but an answer should have some sort of documentation or explanation backing it up. Even an explanation as to why rolling back the drivers might help would be sufficient.